# Обособлять или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

> Только учитывая интересы обеих
> сторон(,) можно говорить о
> сотрудничестве.

Надо ли запятую ставить? Мне вот кажется, что нет...

Answer (score 3):

Запятая нужна, как и в примере с  измененным порядком слов:

*Говорить о сотрудничестве можно, только учитывая интересы обеих сторон.*

Из Розенталя:

Деепричастный оборот, в начале которого стоят частицы *только, лишь*, **интонационно не отделяется** от предшествующей части предложения (при чтении пауза перед ним не делается), **но запятая перед ним обычно ставится**:

*Понять это произведение можно, только учитывая условия его создания.*

*Выучить иностранный язык можно, лишь постоянно занимаясь им.*

Но (при тесном слиянии оборота со сказуемым): *Они встретились только будучи уже взрослыми*.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна, деепричастный оборот стоит перед глаголом-сказуемым и указывает на добавочное действие, частица только усиливает значение этого действия. Была бы не нужна, если бы оборот стоял в конце предложения и утратил глагольное значение:Говорить о сотрудничестве можно только учитывая интересы обеих сторон.

Comment: а мне кажется, это не добавочное действие, а скорее обстоятельство, близкое по значению к наречию. Потому и засомневалась.
Это вроде как "Танцуя вошла я в комнату" - где "танцуя" отвечает на вопрос не "что делая?", а "как?"

Comment: Положение перед глаголом-сказуемым указывает на глагольный приоритет, наречное значение появляется в конце предложения:В комнату я вошла (как?)танцуя. Танцуя вошла я в комнату - неясный смысл, оторванный от контекста, с фразовым ударением на первое слово.Как если бы кто-то спрашивал: "Как ты вошла в комнату?", а дальше бы следовал ответ: "Танцуя..." В обычном смысле тоже просится запятая.(Что делая?)Шутя, я подошёл к ребятам-деепричастие.Он делал это(как?) шутя(т.е. легко)-наречие.

Answer (score 1):

Совершенно справедливо Людмила предлагает два решения:
(1)Только учитывая интересы обеих сторон,можно говорить о сотрудничестве.
(2)Говорить о сотрудничестве можно только учитывая интересы обеих сторон.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Информацию в приведенном сообщении можно выразить с помощью двух синтаксических форм: осложненного предложения с обособленным обстоятельством и простого предложения. Сравним их по семантике, грамматике, интонационной структуре.

Здесь возможны два решения: а)предложение можно подчеркнуто разделить на две  части  в рамках осложненного предложения; б) предложение можно представить как единую конструкцию без паузы (тема-рема)в рамках простого предложения.

Обратим внимание на перестройку второго предложения: "Говорить о сотрУдничестве можно (перелом интонации)только учитывая интересы обЕих сторон". Слово "можно" не имеет тонического ударения и как бы заполняет собой паузу. Только такая структура позволяет нам считать это предложение простым.

ЗАМЕЧАНИЯ

1)Обособить можно любое обстоятельство, даже выраженное одиночным наречием, подобрав соответствующую форму предложения. Поэтому надо анализировать структуру конкретного предложения, а не значения отдельных слов.  Сравнить: Князь шёл задумавшись. - Задумавшись, князь шёл по тропинке.

2) Примеры лучше не придумывать ("Танцуя вошла я в комнату"), а брать из живого текста, (иначе можно рассматривать нереальные варианты), например: "... половая щётка, щетиной вверх, танцуя, влетела в спальню". "Танцуя, она смотрела с улыбкой в стену". "Девушки чуть не танцуя несли корзины с хлопком".

Comment: По существу. Не надо придумывать предложения, которые не встречаются в жизни, и разбирать их как образцово-показательные (так называемые учебные примеры, по-моему, очень вредны). Структура предложения, его значение, интонация  и пунктуационное оформление  зависит от всего текста в целом - РЕАЛЬНОГО текста, а не придуманного. А "щётка"  - из романа "Мастер и Маргарита", пользоваться примерами  из классики особенно удобно.

Comment: А "щётка" - из романа "Мастер и Маргарита"...

то есть это пример из реальной жизни??

Comment: Конечно, из реальной. Щетки и метлы - это весьма распространенный способ перемещения в пространстве.